# Finding $\int \frac{\cos(2x) dx}{\cos^4x+\sin^4x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \frac{\cos(2x) dx}{\cos^4x+\sin^4x}$

I'm looking more into simplifying this than the solution itself (which I know involves using t=tan(x/2)).

I did:

$$\int \frac{\cos(2x) dx}{\cos^4x+\sin^4x} = \int\frac{\cos(2x)dx}{(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x} = \int\frac{\cos(2x)dx}{1-2\sin^2(2x)}$$

I tried applying the t=tan(y/2) (where y = 2x) but it became a mess so I figure this can be simplified further... help?

Comment: Why not $t=\sin(2x)$?

Comment: @clathratus the point of this exercise was to practice the t=tan(x/2) types of substitutions... but why t=sin(2x)?

Comment: Also, you made a typo : $$2\sin^2 x \cos^2 x = \tfrac12 \sin^2(2x).$$

Comment: Because if $t=\sin(2x)$ then $\frac12dt=\cos(2x)dx$ which you have on top

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{\cos2x}{\cos^4x+\sin^4x} dx\\
= &\int\frac{\cos2x}{1-\frac12\sin^2 2x}dx
=\int \frac{d(\sin 2x)}{2-\sin^2 2x}
=\frac1 {\sqrt2} \tanh^{-1} \frac{\sin 2x}{\sqrt2}+C 
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We know that
$$\begin{align}
\cos(2x) &= \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)\\
\sin(x) &= \dfrac{\tan(x)}{\sec(x)}\\
\sec^2(x) &= 1 + \tan^2(x)
\end{align}$$
So,
$$\int\dfrac{\cos(2x)}{\sin^4(x)+\cos^4(x)}\,\mathrm dx \equiv \int\sec^2x\left(\dfrac{-(\tan(x) - 1)(\tan(x) + 1)}{\tan^4(x) + 1}\right)\,\mathrm dx$$
Let $u = \tan(x)$. So, $\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} = \sec^2(x)\to\mathrm dx = \dfrac{\mathrm du}{\sec^2(x)}$.
$$\implies\int\sec^2x\left(\dfrac{-(\tan(x) - 1)(\tan(x) + 1)}{\tan^4(x) + 1}\right)\,\mathrm dx\equiv-\int\dfrac{(u - 1)(u + 1)}{u^4 + 1}\mathrm du$$
Now, you should be able to factor the denominator and use partial fractions to get the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Set $t=\sin(2x)$ so that $\frac12dt=\cos(2x)dx$. Then, as @Azif00 noted, your integral would be $$\int\frac{1}{1-\frac12 t^2}\frac{dt}2=\int\frac{dt}{2-t^2}.$$
You can compute this with partial fractions or a substitution.

Alternatively, you could use $u=\tan(x)$ so that
$$\sin(2x)=\frac{2u}{1+u^2},$$
$$\cos(2x)=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2},$$
and $$dx=\frac{2du}{1+u^2}.$$
Then we have your integral as
$$2\int\frac{1}{1-\frac12(\tfrac{2u}{1+u^2})^2}\frac{1-u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}du\\
=2\int\frac{1-u^2}{u^4+1}du,$$
the rest of which I leave to you as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Continues, we have $$ \int{ \frac{1}{2 - t^2} dt } $$.
assume $ t = \sqrt{2} \sin (y) $, we differensial and get $ dt = \sqrt{2} \cos (y) dy $
$$ \int{ \frac{1}{2 - t^2} dt } = \frac{1}{2} \int{ \frac{\sqrt{2} \cos (y) dy}{1 - \sin ^2 (y) } dt } = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \int{ \sec(y) dy } = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sec y \tan y = \frac{1}{2- t^2}$$ . back to question

Answer (score 2):

$\cos^4 x = \frac 18 (\cos 4x + 4\cos 2x + 3)\\
\sin^4 x = \frac 18 (\cos 4x - 4\cos 2x + 3)\\
\cos^4 x+ \sin^4 x = \frac 14(\cos 4x + 3)$

$\frac {4\cos 2x}{\cos 4x + 3}$

That looks a little better.

Lets say $\cos 4x = 1 - 2\sin^2 2x$

$\int \frac {4\cos 2x}{4 - 2\sin^2 2x}\ dx$

Now we can do a u-subtitution

$u = \sin 2x, du = 2\cos 2x$

$\int \frac {2}{4 - 2u^2}\ du$

Separate into partial fractions

$\frac 1{2\sqrt 2} \int \frac {1}{\sqrt 2-u} + \frac {1}{\sqrt 2+u} \ du$

$\frac 1{2\sqrt 2} (\ln (\sqrt 2+u)-\ln (\sqrt 2-u))$

$\frac 1{2\sqrt 2} (\ln (\sqrt 2+\sin 2x)-\ln (\sqrt 2-\sin 2x))$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos^4x+\sin^4x} \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\cos^4x+\sin^4x} \, dx \\
&= \int \frac{1-2\sin^2x}{1-2\sin^2x+2\sin^4x} \, dx \\
&= - \frac1{\sqrt2} \int \frac{1-2\frac{1-y}{1+y}}{1-2\frac{1-y}{1+y}+2\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2}} \, \frac{dy}{(1+y)\sqrt y \sqrt{1-y}} \tag1 \\
&= \frac1{\sqrt2} \int \frac{1-3y}{1-2y+5y^2} \, \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y-y^2}} \\
&= -\sqrt2 \int \frac{z^2-2}{z^4+4} \, dz \tag2 \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \int \left(\frac{z+1}{\frac{z^2}2+z+1} - \frac{z-1}{\frac{z^2}2-z+1}\right) \, dz \tag3 \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \ln\left(\frac{z^2+2z+2}{z^2-2z+2}\right) + C \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \ln\left(\frac{1+y+2\sqrt{y-y^2}}{1+y-2\sqrt{y-y^2}}\right) + C \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\sin^4x-\cos^4x}}{1-\sqrt{1-\sin^4x-\cos^4x}}\right) + C
\end{align*}$$

(provided $0\le \sin x<1$)

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $\sin x=\sqrt{\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}}$
- $(2)$ : [substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#Euler%27s_third_substitution) $z=\dfrac{\sqrt{y-y^2}}y$
- $(3)$ : partial fractions